# Odd behaviour in gravity from different directions matter js phaser 3

Tags: phaser-framework, matter.js

I'm making a platformer game, in which I have a powerup that lets you fly. On collision, I removed the powerup using `powerup.gameObject.destroy()` and disabled gravity using `player.setIgnoreGravity(true)`. Now when I touch the powerup from different directions, it produces a different result like shown below.
[image: Case 1: Approach from above]

[image: Case 2: Approach from side]

Here's a minimal example: https://jsfiddle.net/prateek_1/rsoj0h2z/

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the code works as it should, here is why:

**Scenario 1)**
you touch the `powerup` while **not** touching the `platform` (`playertouchingground==false`) -> no gravity, and the player doesn't fall to the ground. AND because the player is in the air you can't jump.

**Scenario 2)**
you touch the `powerup` while touching the `platform` (`playertouchingground==true`)  -> no gravity, now you can jump, and when you jump you fly away, since nothing is "pulling" the player down.

*The question is, what do you want to happen, when the objects collide?*

Comment: I need scenario 2. Will just giving it a y velocity after touching the powerup work?

Comment: @Prateekp Yes, that will work.